# Delete all resources with no properties in Apache Jena?

Tags: api, rdf, jena

Is there a way in Apache Jena to remove all resources from the current model, which do not have any properties?

I only found how to delete certain triples, but not something like iterating the resources, checking how much properties they have, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't exist because there is no need for it to exist.  The RDF data model describes a Graph based upon triples where the subject and objects map to Resources in the Jena parlance and the predicates map to properties.

It is not possible to have a resource without any properties thus there is no need for a method to remove such resources to exist.

For iterating the resources try the `listSubjects()` and `listObjects()` methods

To get the number of properties associated with a specific resource you can use the `listStatements()` method to get a `StmtIterator` and then count the statements returned by that e.g.

```
//Assuming you have a Model in variable model
//Assuming you already have some Resource in variable res
StmtIterator stmts = model.listStatements(res, null, null);
int count = 0;
while (stmts.hasNext())
{
  count++;
  stmts.next();
}
```

If you want to count a whole variety of things (e.g. number of properties for each resource) at once you may want to use a SPARQL query instead e.g.

```
SELECT ?s (COUNT(?p) AS ?NumProperties)
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } GROUP BY ?s
```

See [the documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/) for how to run SPARQL queries.